# My django model joining wrong fields when there are multiple related fields with join

Tags: python, django, django-models

My product model has two different relationship with category model:

1. One to One
2. One to Many through ProductShadowCategory table.

Now the situation is when I tried to fetch using the second relationship, I am getting the result from my first relationship.

For example this is what I am trying to print:

```
Category.objects.get(slug="root").shadow_products.all()
```

but it converts to following sql :

```
print(Category.objects.get(slug="root").shadow_products.all().query)

SELECT `product_management_product`.`id`, `product_management_product`.`slug`, `product_management_product`.`category_id`, `product_management_product`.`brand_id` FROM `product_management_product` WHERE `product_management_product`.`category_id` = 720
```

My models looks like following:

```
class Category(SlugableModel):
    #...
    shadow_products = models.ManyToManyField("product_management.Product", through="product_management.ProductShadowCategory")

class Product(SlugableModel):
    #...
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="products", validators=[leaf_category])

class ProductShadowCategory(MyModel):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('category', 'product')
```

Comment: Your SQL qurey says, `select .... FROM product_management_product`, which is the second relation, right?

Comment: it is querying on the first relationship @JPG. but I was expecting to run on second relationship.

Comment: Are expecting something like this, `select .... FROM Category` ?

Comment: a join with `ProductShadowCategory` table